# How to change firefox icons in application (css)

Tags: css, firefox

I want the old firefox logo to show in new tab. I tried editing userChrome.css and userContent.css but it didn't work. Current code is:

```
@-moz-document url("about:newtab") {
    .search-wrapper .logo-and-wordmark .logo{
        background: url("firefoxlogo.png") no-repeat center !important;
        background-size: auto !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question might be better suited for https://superuser.stackexchange.com

Comment: ok i will post it there